# SQLite C API how to save query output to a string

Tags: c, sqlite

The function `showGenres` runs a select query to print to the console the contents of the SQL table genres. I would like to save that result from the `SELECT * FROM genres` query to my `char genresDisplay[1000]` variable.

I have tried using strcat to concatenate a `sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)` to a variable, then printing the variable, but that didn't work. I've also tried doing `sprintf()` but that didn't work either.

```
void showGenres()
{
    int genre_count = 0;
    char genresDisplay[100000];
    char genreID[1000], genreName[1000], genreDescription[1000];

    rc = sqlite3_open("topmusic.db", &database);
    if (rc)
        printf("Error opening database. \n");
    else
        printf("Database opened successfully. \n");
    asprintf(&query, "SELECT * FROM genres;");
    printf("The following SQL Query will run: '%s'\n", query);
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, strlen(query), &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        printf("Can't retrieve data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    printf("%16s | %32s | %48s\n", "ID", "Genre", "Description");
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
         printf("%16s | %32s | %48s\n",
               sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0),
               sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1),
               sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2));
        genre_count++;
    }
    printf("Number of genres: %d\n", genre_count);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    free(query);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The function prints to the console the following:

```
Database opened successfully. 
The following SQL Query will run: 'SELECT * FROM genres;'
              ID |                            Genre |                                      Description
               1 |                              pop |                                           (null)
               2 |                             rock |                                           (null)
               3 |                            blues |                                           (null)
               4 |                        classical |                                           (null)
               5 |                            dance |                                           (null)
               6 |                        hard rock |                                                 
               7 |                            metal |                                   No description
               8 |                      heavy metal |                                    a description
               9 |                             test |                                   No description
              10 |                         pop rock |                                   No description
              11 |                             exit |                                   No description
              12 |                            test2 |                                   No description
              13 |                            test3 |                                   No description
              14 |                            test4 |                                   No description
              15 |                        asdasdasd |                                   No description
Number of genres: 15
```

How can I save this output to a variable?

Comment: *I have tried using strcat to concatenate a sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) to a variable, then printing the variable, but that didn't work.* - tell us how you tried it and how it didn't work.

Comment: int offset=0; while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)){ offset+= sprintf(genresDisplay+offset, "%16s | %32s | %48s\n", ****);} . But be careful - you will get stack overflow eventually

Comment: This set of sqlite functions make handling the memory management easy: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/str.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a huge array and hoping you don't get a stack overflow as a result when calling your function (Or a small one that ends up not being big enough), it's better to allocate the memory you're using dynamically with `malloc()`, and growing as needed with `realloc()` to be able to hold all the results. This is tedious and error-prone, though. Luckily, Sqlite provides [some functions](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/str.html) to manage a dynamically grown string buffer for you.

Using that API your code might look like

```
...
sqlite3_str *buffer = sqlite3_str_new(database);
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    sqlite3_str_appendf(buffer, "%16s | %32s | %48s\n",
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0),
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1),
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2));
    genre_count++;
}
// Don't forget to free genreDisplay with sqlite3_free() when done.
char *genreDisplay = sqlite3_str_finish(buffer);
...
```